# fireEvent.change outputs weird number on changer slider/range value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'd like to change an input range value with `fireEvent.change` to check that a user can effectively change it. Oddly, the test output shows me a really strange number that doesn't give me much info about what's going wrong with it.

This is my test:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import {cleanup,render,screen, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react';
import Carrier from './carrier';
import Settings from './settings.json'

beforeEach(()=>{
  cleanup();
})

  it(`changes volume level`,()=>{
    render(<Carrier settings={Settings}/>);
    const volume = screen.getByRole(`slider`,{name:`volume`});
    expect(Settings.carrier.volume).toEqual(1);

    fireEvent.change(volume, {target:{value:`0.32`}});
    expect(Settings.carrier.volume).toEqual(0.32);
  })
```

Output:

```
  ● Rendering › changes volume level

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: 0.32
    Received: -9.89700043360188

      49 |
      50 |     fireEvent.change(volume, {target:{value:`0.32`}});
    > 51 |     expect(Settings.carrier.volume).toEqual(0.32);
         |                                     ^
      52 |   })
      53 | });
      54 |
```

Component:

```
const Carrier = ({settings}) =>{

  function handleWaveformChoice(e){
    if(e.target.checked)
      settings.carrier.type = e.target.value;
  }

  function handleVolumeChange(e){
    settings.carrier.volume = Math.log10(e.target.value)*20;
  }
  return(
    <>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Waveform</legend>
          <label>
           <input value='sine' name='sine' type='radio' onClick={handleWaveformChoice}/>
            sine
          </label>
          <label>
           <input value='square' name='square' type='radio' onClick={handleWaveformChoice}/>
            square
          </label>
          <label>
           <input value='triangle' name='triangle' type='radio' onClick={handleWaveformChoice}/>
            triangle
          </label>
          <label>
           <input value='sawtooth' name='sawtooth' type='radio' onClick={handleWaveformChoice}/>
            sawtooth
          </label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <label>
          <input value={settings.carrier.volume} name='volume' type='range' min="0.0001" step="1" max="1" onChange={handleVolumeChange}/>
          volume
        </label>
      </fieldset>
    </>
  );
}

export default Carrier;
```

Attempts to solve the problem:

- Unfortunately, `userEvent` doesn't have a similar feature I could rely on. Tried to use it once and confirmed later that I wouldn't be able to.
- `const volume = screen.getByRole(`slider`,{name:`volume`}) as HTMLInputElement;` linting tells me that this sort of assertions can only be used in Typescript files.
- Verified with `console.log` that `fireEvent` was actually doing something with the range input I was trying to test. It definitely did change the value but again I couldn't find out why the weird output.

Can anyone point me out what I'm missing or doing wrong with this test please?

Comment: You have `settings.carrier.volume = Math.log10(e.target.value)*20;`

Comment: So in your test you’d expect it `toEqual(Math.log10(0.32) * 20)`

Comment: Hi @James! You're basically right. There's nothing wrong with my code at all, I completely missed I'm scaling values to fit a proper volume log scale. Thanks for making me realize that.

Answer (score 0):

James pointed out that I'd coded a math formula that was influencing the output of the test. I didn't have actually a bug but I completely missed I'd aimed to convert `range` input values into a number within a logarithmic scale that matched volume properly.

This is the passing test:

```
it(`changes volume level`,()=>{
  render(<Carrier settings={Settings}/>);
  const volume = screen.getByRole(`slider`,{name:`volume`});
  expect(Settings.carrier.volume).toEqual(1);

  fireEvent.change(volume, {target:{value:`0.32`}});
  expect(Settings.carrier.volume).toEqual(-9.89700043360188);
  expect(volume.value).toBe(`0.32`);
});
```

Also my input volume isn't updating properly because it reads the scaled value from `Settings.carrier.volume` instead of reflection users' actions.

```
import {useState} from "react";

const Carrier = ({settings}) =>{
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState(0.75);

  function handleVolumeChange(e){
    settings.carrier.volume = Math.log10(e.target.value)*20;
    setVolume(e.target.value);
  }
  return(
    <>
      <label>
        <input value={volume} name='volume' type='range' min="0.0001" step="1" max="1" onChange={handleVolumeChange}/>
        volume
      </label>
    </>
  );
}

export default Carrier;
```